# Monitor timeout on a socket fd

Tags: sockets, timer

Requirement: My server is assigning a task to a client, and the client has to respond within 1 minute, else, I need to take some action.

The entire codebase is in C.

What Linux/socket programming mechanism can I employ to monitor a socket fd and raise an event if no write has happened on that socket for more than some given time (say 1 minute) ?

Comment: In general if using blocking I/O, the standard `SO_SNDTIMEO` and `SO_RECVTIMEO` should be sufficient. Otherwise, you will need to use `select` (or equivalents) and check the return value of `select` itself. You might also want to avail yourself of an event loop such as _libev_ or _libevent_

Comment: The connection fds with the client are in an epoll..how ever what i want is to be notified if the client has not responded within a timeout (e.g client down). Afaik, SO_SNDTIMEO and SO_RECVTIMEO is only to make sure your i/o calls dont block forever

Comment: _The connection fds with the client are in an epoll_ - in your question, you talk of only one _socket fd_, in the comment above of multiple _connection fds_; what is really the case?